# Module no found after "ng build --prod"

Tags: angular, build, routes, production-environment, angular-cli

After execute `ng build --prod`, I can not open sub modules (lazy loading).

`market.module.js` is not being generated by the build.

Error:

```
zone.js:1263 GET http://192.168.1.10/dist/app/+market/market.module.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Environment:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
node: 6.3.1
os: linux x64
```

app.routing.ts:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CompanyGuard } from './shared/guards/company.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'company/:company_id',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'market',
                loadChildren: 'app/+market/market.module#MarketModule',
            }
        ],
        canActivate: [ CompanyGuard ]
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `+` from the path and references to that path? A number of web servers do not like that prefix char. That and changes in routing strategies have lead to that convention being dropped.

Comment: Before already I was without +. I put it to see if it solved